# How can I get Jupyter-notebook syntax highlighting in VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I installed Visual Studio Code, and want to customize syntax highlight to be the same as Jupyter notebook. I'm using default light theme and that's good but colors of python built-in functions and methods aren't.

What should I do?

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get the exact highlights of the standard jupyter notebook, but VS Code has a huge collection of themes which will apply various syntax highlight styles for your notebooks. Try checking out if one of the themes under the extensions tab might suit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

Since the code itself is written in `python`, as long as you have the language support you should get the Syntax Highlighting, Autocomplete and IntelliSense. See: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python.

For a full walkthrough on setting up a `jupyter-notebook` see: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a theme for that on the [VS Code extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sam-the-programmer.jupyter-theme) site. You should be able to install it from the extensions tab on VS Code itself or through "Install" from that link.

Hope this helps.